# Print works but return value is None when using backtracking to solve a sudoku

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking, sudoku

I have written the following code to solve a Sudoku game with the backtracking method. It is possible to print the correct result, but I haven't found a way to get the same result as return value instead of printing it. How do I have to change the program to make it work?

```
import numpy as np

def find_possible(sudoku,r,c):
    """returns the possible Values as numpy array for a given position"""
    position = sudoku[r, c]
    if position == 0:
        line = sudoku[r, :]
        column = sudoku[: ,c]
        r0 = (r//3)*3
        c0 = (c//3)*3
        square = sudoku[r0:r0+3,c0:c0+3]
        numbers = np.arange(1, 10)
        blocked_numbers = np.unique(np.append(np.append(line,column),square))
        return np.setdiff1d(numbers,blocked_numbers)
    else: return np.array([])

def backtrack(sudoku):
    """solve the game with the backtracking method"""
    for r in range(9):
        for c in range(9):
            list_of_possible = find_possible(sudoku,r, c)
            if sudoku[r,c] == 0:
                for i in range(len(list_of_possible)):
                    sudoku[r,c] = list_of_possible[i]
                    backtrack(sudoku)
                    sudoku[r,c] = 0
                return

    result = sudoku
    print(result)

table = np.array([[5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
                  [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],
                  [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
                  [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
                  [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9]])

backtrack(table)
```

**EDIT**

If the `print` is replaced by a `return`, the return value is still `None` because of the first `return`. And if I give the first `return` the value of the sudoku Matrix, the output is not the final result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing the result "back along the track" to the original call of your `backtrack` function. (Result meaning that the sudoku has been solved.) Your `print` works, because you get to that line exactly one time: when your `for` loops finished after there are no zeros left. However, the solving doesn't stop there and your "tree" of `backtrack` calls continues. You can verify this by looking at `table`: at some point it had been fully solved (no zeros left), but if you print it at the end, there will be zeros in there again.

With the following changes, your function either returns `None` (like you had before, I just added the `None` for explicitness) or the solved sudoku in `sudoku`. Inside the `for` loop, `result` stores the result of the call to `backtrack` and we can test if the result was `None` (and we have to keep on solving) or we're done and can return `result` (either to the previous `backtrack` call, or to the original call outside the function).

```py
def backtrack(sudoku):
    """solve the game with the backtracking method"""
    for r in range(9):
        for c in range(9):
            list_of_possible = find_possible(sudoku, r, c)
            if sudoku[r, c] == 0:
                for i in range(len(list_of_possible)):
                    sudoku[r, c] = list_of_possible[i]
                    result = backtrack(sudoku)
                    if result is not None:
                        return result
                    sudoku[r, c] = 0
                return None
    return sudoku
```

By the way, the `result` name is just another reference to the same object as `sudoku`. I thought it might help understand what's happening, but you don't really need it:

```py
def backtrack(sudoku):
    """solve the game with the backtracking method"""
    for r in range(9):
        for c in range(9):
            list_of_possible = find_possible(sudoku, r, c)
            if sudoku[r, c] == 0:
                for i in range(len(list_of_possible)):
                    sudoku[r, c] = list_of_possible[i]
                    if backtrack(sudoku) is not None:
                        return sudoku
                    sudoku[r, c] = 0
                return None
    return sudoku
```

Also, try to start using a linter like Pylint or flake8 which will analyze your code a little bit for some improvements. For example, in Python, instead of

```
for i in range(len(list_of_possible)):
```

you can just write

```
for possible in list_of_possible:
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `return` statement. Instead of `print(result)`, use `return result`

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work that easily. If I replace `print` with `return`, the return value still remains `None` because of the first `return`. And if I give the first `return` the value of the Sudoku puzzle, I don't get the final result